# actionscript 2.0 read XML file

Tags: xml, actionscript

I'm trying to read an XML file with actionscript 2.0

The problem is I can only make my code to read a value of a tag by referencing their position.

e.g.
`var currentIcon = myXML.firstChild.firstChild.childNodes[0].firstChild;`

How do I retrieve a value from an XMl file by referencing their tag name?

e.g.
`var currentIcon = myXML.firstChild.firstChild.childNodes['icon'].firstChild;`

Here is my XML file...

```
<weather>
    <current>
        <icon>Partly cloudy</icon>
        <temphigh>33</temphigh>
        <templow>24</templow>
        <humhigh>55</humhigh>
        <humlow>95</humlow>
    </current>
    <forecast1>
        <day>Monday</day>
        <icon>rss_ts2</icon>
        <temphigh>33</temphigh>
        <templow>24</templow>
    </forecast1>
    <forecast2>
        <day>Tuesday</day>
        <icon>rss_ts2</icon>
        <temphigh>32</temphigh>
        <templow>23</templow>
    </forecast2>
    <forecast3>
        <day>Wednesday</day>
        <icon>rss_ts2</icon>
        <temphigh>32</temphigh>
        <templow>23</templow>
    </forecast3>
</weather>
```

Answer (score 1):

In AS2 you can't directly retrieve a node by name from the `childNodes` array (you can do it in AS3 with E4X and dot notation). You should convert your loaded `XML` into a native AS2 Object using an `XML2Object` parser like this:

http://www.sephiroth.it/weblog/archives/2004/01/xml2object.php

Then you will access your `XML` with dot notation like `weather.current.icon`.
The link contains the `XML2Object` AS2 class and some examples.

This link explains difference about how to handle XML documents in AS2 and AS3:
http://www.thetechlabs.com/tech-tutorials/xml/working-with-xml-e4x-and-actionscript-3/